# Stubby: stub PUT requests for same URLS with distinct body

Tags: javascript, stubby4j

I'd like to match distinct bodies for the same PUT URL, but stubby4j always matches the first case, no matter what's the content of the body.

Example:

```
- request:
    url: /individuals/.*/address$
    method: PUT
    body: >
      {
        "type": "MOBILE",
        (other input fields)  
      }
  response:
    status: 400
    body: >
      {
        "type": "BAD_REQUEST",
        "message": "Validation error on request."
      }
- request:
    url: /individuals/.*/address$
    method: PUT
    body: >
      {
        "type": "HOME",
        (other input fields)
      }
  response:
    status: 200
```

In this case, no matter what's the value of the parameter "type" in my request, it always matches with the first stub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the late response.

In the recent & current versions of stubby4j (i.e.: `7.x.x`) it is possible to match distinct bodies for the same `PUT`/`GET`/`POST`/`PATCH`/etc URLs.

For example, the following is a valid YAML config that would work (I simplified a tad the YAML config provided by the OP for the sake of example):

```
-  request:
      url: /individuals/.*/address$
      method: PUT
      post: >
        {"type": "MOBILE"}

   response:
      status: 400
      body: >
        {"type": "BAD_REQUEST"}


-  request:
      url: /individuals/.*/address$
      method: PUT
      post: >
        {"type": "HOME"}

   response:
      body: OK
      status: 200
```

To note:

- The `request` does not get the `body` key, use `post` key instead for stubbing your payload for POST/PUT/PATCH (or `file` if your payload is too big)
- The `body` key should only be used in `response`, not `request`
- The `json` key is invalid & not supported by [stubby4j](https://stubby4j.com)

Please refer to the stubby4j user manual for more information about the YAML config for `request` & `response`:
https://stubby4j.com/docs/http_endpoint_configuration_howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the request body to json data with headers.

```
- request:
    url: /individuals/.*/address$
    method: PUT
    headers:
       content-type: application/json
    json: '{"type": "MOBILE"}'
  response: ...

- request:
    url: /individuals/.*/address$
    method: PUT
    headers:
       content-type: application/json
    json: '{"type": "HOME"}'
  response: ...
```